# Selection formula does not work crystal report

Tags: c#, date, crystal-reports

i have sales table in oracle database , insert some value 
when i have write below the query i have get 100 perfect out put

```
> crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{sales.salesdate} >= '"
> +'01/12/2017'+ "' and {sales.salesdate} <= '"31/12/2017 + "'";
```

when next time write query in C# for view report as same

```
>  crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{sales.salesdate} >= '" +
> fromddate1 + "' and {sales.salesdate} <= '" + todate1 + "'";
```

[date picker value from date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMtP9.png)

[date picker value to date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohzNO.png)

and show the error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqmil.png)

my backend date formate dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: {sales.salesdate} doesn't exist in database

Comment: no, when i have write code sql plus i have get  100% right outpu

Comment: are you able to extract the query from crystal report